# read json file from codeigniter controller

Tags: php, android, json, codeigniter

i try to read a json file with android application from codeigniter controller but don't work.
i use Volley library.
i get this error:
**E/Volley: [311] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for**

```
  public void lookForBanner() {
    RequestQueue MyRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    String url = General.serveur + General.controller;
    StringRequest MyStringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            System.out.println("RESPONSE================"+response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    }){
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> MyData = new HashMap<String, String>();
            MyData.put("id",key);
            return MyData;
        }
    }; ;
    MyRequestQueue.add(MyStringRequest);
}
```

for the controller

```
   public function myFunction() {
    $this->load->model('ClientModel');
    $this->load->model('monModel');
    $id = null;
    if (!empty($_POST['id'])) {
     $id = $_POST['id'];
    $resultat = $this->ClientModel->get_Result($this->monModel->get_Publicmon($id)->id);
    $result['title']=$resultat->title;
    $result['desc']=$resultat->description;
    $response['Resultat'] = $result;
    echo json_encode($response, TRUE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try putting `exit` after `json_encode(($response, TRUE)`.